# How do you use relative date to show last 10 weeks, while still getting last years results for those weeks in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have created a relative date filter that shows the last 10 weeks of sales. Problem is that

i only get the years for those last 10 weeks. What i want is the last 3 years to compare

these 10 weeks of sales. If i choose the last 3 years insted of last 10 weeks i get all

weeks. This i can fix by creating a slicer. The problem is that the slider does not

update itself next week. What i want is something that runs completely automatically.

Any ideas?

---  I can´t use the query editor as this is on a live connection.

Thanks!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @Magnus. Your question is barely understandable. Please make your request stronger by adding some data, model, and even your effort to solve the problem. Then I am sure people will react faster to your problem. Stay safe!